# Find the homogeneous linear DE with constant coefficients of least order that has $y = 1 + 2e^{-2x}\cos x$ as a solution.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the homogeneous linear DE with constant coefficients of least order that
has
$$y = 1 + 2e^{-2x}\cos x$$

as a solution.

Comment: Don’t be so hasty to accept answers, especially when they’re wrong. The accepted answer below doesn’t have constant coefficients as required by your homework problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The general solution of a first order homogeneous DE of the form 
$$ y'(x) + p(x)y = q(x)\tag{1}$$
is given by 
$$ y(x) = \frac{1}{\mu (x)}\int \mu(x) q(x)\tag{2},$$
where $\mu(x) = e^{\int p(x) \ dx}$ is the integrating factor.
\begin{align}
1+2e^{-2x} \cos(x) &= \mu^{-1} (x) \int \mu(x) (0) \ dx = \frac{C}{\mu(x)} \\ \implies& \mu(x) = \frac{C}{1+2e^{-2x}\cos(x)}.
\end{align}
Therefore, 
\begin{align}
 \mu(x) = e^{\int p(x) \ dx} \implies \frac{C}{1+2e^{-2x}\cos(x)} &= e^{\int p(x) \ dx}\\
 \ln\biggl |\frac{C}{1+2e^{-2x}\cos(x)} \biggr| &= \int p(x) \ dx\\
\frac{d}{dt}\ln\biggl |\frac{C}{1+2e^{-2x}\cos(x)} \biggr| &= p(x) \\
\therefore \frac{2\sin(x)+4\cos(x)}{e^{2x}+2\cos(x)} &= p(x).
\end{align}
Finally , using $(1)$, the initial differential equation is 
$$y' + \left(\frac{2\sin(x)+4\cos(x)}{e^{2x}+2\cos(x)} \right)y = 0$$

Comment: Your differential equation does not have constant coefficients. Nowhere in the task is a restriction to first order DE mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution function has terms for the eigenvalues $0,-2\pm i$ without polynomial factors for multiplicities, so that your DE can be read off as
$$
(D-0)(D+2+i)(D+2-i)y=0
$$